# What do these notations mean, if we read those in English?

Tags: probability, cryptography

If m: message, M: message space, k: key, K: keyspace, c: cipher, C: cipher space and $E_k$: encryption function, such that
$E_k(m) = c,\ m,m^* \in M,\ k\in K,\ c\in C.$

Then, what do the following notations actually mean in plain English?
\begin{eqnarray*}P[m=m^* | E_k(m) = c] = \frac1{|M|}\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}P[m=m^*] = P[E_k(m) = E_k(m^*)]\end{eqnarray*}

I am trying the notation to match it with   https://www.lri.fr/~fmartignon/documenti/systemesecurite/3-OneTimePad.pdf    and   https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs387/l-48735205/e-48734451/m-48738141   to understand it.

Comment: The first reads, "given that the encryption function $E_k$ using key $k$ applied to message $m$ returns the cipher $c$, the probability that two messages, $m$ and $m^*$, are equal is $\frac{1}{|\mu|}$".  The second line reads "The probability that two messages, $m$ and $m^*$ are the same is equal to the probability that their encrypted messages, $E_k(m)$ and $E_k(m^*)$, are the same."

Comment: @JMoravitz You should turn that into the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first reads, "given that the encryption function $E_k$ using key $k$ applied to message $m$ returns the cipher $c$, the probability that two messages, $m$ and $m^∗$, are equal is $\frac{1}{|M|}$."

The second line reads "The probability that two messages, $m$ and $m^∗$ are the same is equal to the probability that their encrypted messages, $E_k(m)$ and $E_k(m^∗)$, are the same."

---

In particular, it is worth noting what the symbols used in each statement mean.  The symbol $P[A]$ represents the probability measure which assigns a value between (inclusive) zero and one to the event, $A$, enclosed in the brackets.

When there is a vertical bar inside of the brackets however, it is a *conditional probability*.  $P[A|B] := \frac{P[A\cap B]}{P[B]}$, and is read aloud as "the probability of $A$ given $B$" and has the interpretation of "supposing that we know ahead of time that $B$ is true/hashappened, the probability that $A$ is also true is ..."

Here also we have another remark to be made about notation, often times you will see $P[A]$ where $A$ is an event which is defined elsewhere.  In our case, we see the event being defined inside of the brackets.  $P[m=m^*]$ is the probability of the event that $m=m^*$, i.e. the probability that the two messages $m$ and $m^*$ are actually the same.

Comment: If I read it as, "given that the random variable $E_k$ takes on the value $c$, the probability that, $m$ takes on the value $m^∗$, is $\frac{1}{|M|}$." .....does this thing mean anything?

Comment: That should mean exactly what you intend it to mean, though it depends on the context whether $E_k$ is in fact a random variable.,  I would consider $m$ the random variable under normal circumstances.

Comment: I am trying the notation to match it with   https://www.lri.fr/~fmartignon/documenti/systemesecurite/3-OneTimePad.pdf    and   https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs387/l-48735205/e-48734451/m-48738141   to understand it.

Comment: If you check the links, I don't think, your assumption that 'm is a random variable' is correct.